# Getting the top N values and their coordinates from a 2D Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array "bigrams" of shape (851, 851) with float values inside. I want to get the top ten values from this array and I want their coordinates.

I know that `np.amax(bigrams)` can return the single highest value, so that's basically what I want but then for the top ten.

As a numpy-noob, I wrote some code using a loop to get the top values per row and then using `np.where()` to get the coordinates, but i feel there must be a smarter way to solve this..

Comment: Could you post a small array and the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten and use argsort.

```
idxs = np.argsort(bigrams.ravel())[-10:]
rows, cols = idxs//851, idxs%851
print(bigrams[rows,cols])
```

An alternative would be to do a partial sorting with argpartition.

```
partition = np.argpartition(bigrams.ravel(),-10)[-10:]
max_ten = bigrams[partition//851,partition%851]
```

You will get the top ten values and their coordinates, but they won't be sorted. You can sort this smaller array of ten values later if you want.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed. I found you can also use `np.unravel_index()` to get back to the original 2D array's coordinates. That feels a bit more descriptive to me.